# Why my Log4j 2Mongo appender does not log anything in MongoDB4?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, logging, log4j

I am using the java language and ***spring*** framework for writing my code. I decided to add a logger, and I found out that using Log4j2 is proper for my work. When I started to use it with ***Mongodb*** version 4, I faced a big problem that I don't know the problem. Actually, it doesn't log anything. My related codes are as follows:

***Build.gradle:***

```
        implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.7'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.0'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.0'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-nosql', version: '2.9.1'
```

***log4j2.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <NoSql name="MongoDbAppender">
            <MongoDb4 connection="mongodb://mongouser:mongoPassword@mongoServer:mongoServerPort/dbName.collectanName" />
        </NoSql>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="َALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="MongoDbAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="MongoDbAppender" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="MongoDbAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

***controller which responsible to log for the test:***

```
@GetMapping("/api/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EventController.class);
        logger.error("Hello");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

It should be noted that I use ***intellij idea*** as IDE and *gradle* as build tool.
when I try to test the logger using the above-mentioned API, only the console writes the log and doesn't insert it in MongoDB.

Comment: So you tried adding a logger and didn't succeed? What is your question?

Comment: @D.SM when I try to test the logger using the above-mentioned API, only the console writes the log and doesn't insert it in MongoDB.